# Is there a name for this class of graphs?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

Consider the graphs $G=(V,E)$ where there exists a non-empty $S \subseteq V$ such that $G[S]$ is a complete subgraph and every possible edge between $S$ and $V\setminus S$ is present in $G$. Equivalently, every vertex in $S$ is "universal", that is, is a neighbor of every other vertex in the graph.

I found this class of graphs during my research and I don't know if there is a name for them. Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a special case of $r$-dominating cliques, defined here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X97000769